# Android - FinestWebView API - Fullpage.js - Screen flickers, or is obstructed, or first slide doesn't appear

Tags: javascript, android, fullpage.js

Anyone use the [FinestWebView API](https://github.com/TheFinestArtist/FinestWebView-Android) and set url to a page implementing the [fullpage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) api? When testing the screen does one of these:

- flickers
- whitebox blocks most of screen
- first slide is not visible unless you scroll down several times

At first I thought it might be an issue with my implementation of fullpage.js, but it doesn't even work if I set the url to fullpage.js demo page.

There are several ui manipulations in the FinestWebView API, which I suspect may be the culprit. I'm curious if anyone has encountered this, and if so, how to fix?